about sum of unity roots
$\zeta_p $ is a primitive $p$-th root of unity in $\mathbb C$.for any $d \in N$, define that $G_d=\Sigma_x(\zeta_p)$^$x^d$, for all $x \in F_p$. Show that the degree over $Q$ of $G_d$ is equal to greatest divisor $(d,p-1)$.
It is obvious to see the degree can divide $p-1$, but what about $d$?
I have known another relevant conclusion is that: define $S_k(d)=\Sigma_x(\zeta_p)$^$Tr(x^d)$, for all $x \in F_p^k$, $F_p^k$ is the finite field with $p^k$ elements, $\operatorname{Tr}$ is trace from $F_p^k$ to $F_p$. If $d$ divides $\frac{p^k-1}{p-1}$, then $S_k(d)\in \mathbb Z$.
I think this can help, but I can not come up with it。

I improved the formatting quite a bit, mainly by "adjusting" spacing by removing $'s exiting and almost immediately re-entering math mode. But I didn't know what you meant in the two places where there are ^'s left, so I didn't change that. Please check that I didn't accidentally change the meaning of anything else - and realise that stuff can be mathematics (and should thus be enclosed in $'s) even if it can be typed outside of math mode.
